# Как получить callback из ответа бота в pyrogram

Tags: python, aiogram, pyrogram

У меня есть юзербот для работы с обычным ботом. Мне надо чтобы мой юзербот мог нажимать на кнопки в боте, смотрел в документации(https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/bound-methods/Message.click), там говорят что в аргумент callback_data функции request_callback_answer надо передать `message.reply_markup[i][j].callback_data`, но параметра callback_data у меня в ответе нет.[image: это json в которым должна быть callback_data]

Answer (score 0):

Я перепутал Inline и Reply клавиатуры, поэтому не работало